# Set crosshairs color for a specific series - highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to set the crosshairs color on a multiple series highcharts, i am not sure what is the attribute i should try setting it. I am overiding the refresh method of Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype and trying to access crosshairs object to access its attr()to set the stroke on it. Unfortunately the crosshairs object is coming back null even though i have it set on the global tooltip object -

**HC wrap**

```
 HC.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(p, point, mouseEvent) {
        p.call(this, point, mouseEvent);

        if (point && point.length > 0) {

            var crosshairs = this.crosshairs;
            if (point[0].series.name === 'series1') {
                crosshairs.attr({
                    stroke: '#222222',
                    'stroke-width': 1
                });
            } else {
                label.attr({
                    stroke: COLORS.black,
                    'stroke-width': 0
                });
            }
        } 
    });
```

**Tooltip object on the series** -

```
  tooltip: {
             crosshairs: [{
             width: 1, 
             color: COLORS.gray_1, 
             zIndex: 3
                }, false], 
}
```

What am i missing? Can we style the crosshair in the above manner? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Tried morgan's suggestion below, the event doesn't seem to fire at all.

```
(function (HC) {

   HC.addEvent(Highcharts.Axis, 'afterDrawCrosshair', 
      function (point) {
           if(this.cross && point) {
               this.cross.attr({
                  stroke: COLORS.red
               })
           }
   });

 })(Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the crosshair's stroke after the crosshair is drawn. You can do this in an axis' event `afterDrawCrosshair`:

```
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Axis, 'afterDrawCrosshair', function ({ point }) {
  if (this.cross && point) {
    this.cross.attr({
      stroke: point.series.color
    })
  }
})
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/w6erqkpb/

Comment: i don't see this event firing at all. The below is the code i am using -

    var globalCallback = function (chart) {
    
        // Specific event listener
        Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Axis, 'afterDrawCrosshair', function (point) {
            console.log('Set extremes to ');
        });
    }
    
    // Add `globalCallback` to the list of highcharts callbacks
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(globalCallback);

Comment: can you give me the link to the documentation for the event afterDrawCrossHair?, sorry i wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @arjary Can you adjust the fiddle to show the issue? You can add this event only if use the latest versions of Highcharts. I think it is 6.1 when this event was added. If you use lower version, you should use `wrap` instead of `addEvent` - http://jsfiddle.net/mLd9zwv3/. Those events are not part of official API so they are document in the source code only.